# Grails parse params for Datatable 1.10 ajax request

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using Datable 1.10 server side processing with Grails. New version of Datatable changed the ajax post request format. I am parsing params values like this. its giving the error.

```
println params?.start
println params?.columns[1]?.search?.regex
```

in php they are using count function to loop number of columns like this.

```
for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ )
```

What is the beast to loop this POST params value in grails?

```
columns[2][search][regex]: false
columns[2][searchable]: true
columns[0][search][value]: 
columns[1][orderable]: true
columns[2][name]: 
search[value]: 
columns[1][data]: lastName
columns[1][searchable]: true
draw: 1
columns[0][data]: firstName
length: 5
columns[0][name]: 
columns[0][search][regex]: false
columns[2][data]: dateOfBirth
columns[1][search][value]: 
columns[0][orderable]: true
columns[1][name]: 
columns[2][search][value]: 
order[0][column]: 0
columns[1][search][regex]: false
order[0][dir]: asc
start: 0
columns[0][searchable]: true
columns[2][orderable]: true
search[regex]: false
```

trying to re-write this php code in grails,

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Just came up with this logic. Is there a simple and better logic to do this?

```
int len= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[data\]/ }.size()
    for(int i=0;  i<len; i++){
        def str="columns["+i+"][data]"
        println i + " ==> " + params."$str"
    }
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
int len= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[data\]/ }.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used some of the ideas from above, and came up with the following.

This is by no means a perfect solution.  Note that my UI has per-column filtering/searching, and has the global search disabled.

```
class DataTablesParams {

    Integer length
    Integer draw
    Long start
    Map search
    private DataTablesOrderParams _order
    private Map<Integer, DataTablesColumnsParams> _columns

    /**
     * Gets the "order" DataTables data.
     * <br/>
     * <b>Note:</b> This method cannot be called getOrder() because Grails
     * tries to use that for automatic data-binding which does not work with
     * the syntax used by DataTables.
     * @return DataTablesOrderParams
     */
    DataTablesOrderParams getDataTablesOrder() {
        if (_order == null) {
            _order = new DataTablesOrderParams()
        }
        return _order
    }

    /**
     * Gets the "columns" DataTables data.
     * <br/>
     * <b>Note:</b> This method cannot be called getColumns() because Grails
     * tries to use that for automatic data-binding which does not work with
     * the syntax used by DataTables.
     * 
     * @return Map<Integer, DataTablesColumnsParams> The key to the map is the column     number.
     */
    Map<Integer, DataTablesColumnsParams> getDataTablesColumns() {
        if (_columns == null) {
            _columns = new HashMap()
        }
        return _columns
    }

    DataTablesColumnsParams getColumn(int column) {

        if (getDataTablesColumns().get(column) == null) {
            getDataTablesColumns().put(column, new DataTablesColumnsParams())
        }
        return getDataTablesColumns().get(column)
    }

    String getSearchValueForColumn(String columnName) {

        for (DataTablesColumnsParams p : getDataTablesColumns().values()) {
            if (p.data?.equals(columnName)) {
                return p.searchValue
            }
        }

        return null
    }

    int getColumnCount() {
        return getDataTablesColumns().size()
    }

    void processAdditionalParams(Map params) {

        try {

            getDataTablesOrder().column = Integer.parseInt(params."order[0][column]")
            getDataTablesOrder().dir = params."order[0][dir]"

            int totalMatches

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[name\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).name = params."columns[${i}][name]"
            }

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[data\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).data = params."columns[${i}][data]"
            }

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[column\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).column = Integer.parseInt(params."columns[${i}][column]")
            }

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[searchable\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).searchable = params."columns[${i}][searchable]"
            }

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[orderable\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).orderable = params."columns[${i}][orderable]"
            }

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[search\]\[value\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).searchValue = params."columns[${i}][search][value]"
            }

            totalMatches= params.findAll{ it.key ==~ /columns\[\d+\]\[search\]\[regex\]/ }.size()
            for(int i = 0;  i < totalMatches; i++){
                getColumn(i).searchRegex = params."columns[${i}][search][regex]"
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            println("*** ERROR: processAdditionalParams() " + t)
            throw t
        }
    }

    int getDataTablesOrderColumn() {
        return getDataTablesOrder().column
    }

    String getOrderColumnName() {
        int orderColumn = getDataTablesOrderColumn()
        return getColumnName(orderColumn)
    }

    String getColumnName(Integer columnNumber) {
        /*
         * The column name is in the 'data' element
         */
        return getColumn(columnNumber).data
    }

    String getOrderDirection() {
        return getDataTablesOrder().dir
    }

    boolean isOrderAscending() {
        return getOrderDirection() == 'asc'
    }

    boolean isOrderDescending() {
        return getOrderDirection() != 'asc'
    }

    int getDataTablesColumnsSize() {
        return getDataTablesColumns().size() ?: 0
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(getClass().getSimpleName())
        b.append(" [")

        b.append(" length:").append(length)
        b.append(" draw:").append(draw)
        b.append(" start:").append(start)
        b.append(" search:").append(search)
        b.append(" order:").append(getDataTablesOrder())
        b.append(" columnsSize:").append(getDataTablesColumnsSize())
        b.append(" columns:").append(getDataTablesColumns())
        b.append(" getDataTablesOrderColumn():").append(getDataTablesOrderColumn())
        b.append(" getOrderDirection():").append(getOrderDirection())
        b.append(" getOrderColumnName():").append(getOrderColumnName())

        b.append("]")
        return b.toString()
    }
}
```

Also

```
class DataTablesOrderParams {
    Integer column
    String dir

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(getClass().getSimpleName())
        b.append(" [")

        b.append(" column:").append(column)
        b.append(" dir:").append(dir)

        b.append("]")
        return b.toString()
    }
}
```

And

```
class DataTablesColumnsParams {
    String name
    String data
    Integer column
    String searchValue
    Boolean searchRegex
    Boolean searchable
    String orderable

    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(getClass().getSimpleName())
        b.append(" [")

        b.append(" name:").append(name)
        b.append(" data:").append(data)
        b.append(" column:").append(column)
        b.append(" searchValue:").append(searchValue)
        b.append(" searchRegex:").append(searchRegex)
        b.append(" searchable:").append(searchable)
        b.append(" orderable:").append(orderable)

        b.append("]")
        return b.toString()
    }
}
```

And lastly, the "ugly" bit:

```
def yourControllerMethod(SomeCommandObjectCommand command,
                         DataTablesParams dataTablesParams) {

    /*
     * IMPORTANT: DO THIS FIRST
     */
    dataTablesParams.processAdditionalParams(params)

    <rest of your code>
}
```

Hopefully that helps, or at least gives you some ideas.